# How to replace text in all input tags using javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension, dom-events

I am working on a chrome extension that replaces certain keywords such as TT for Talk to you later. For that purpose, I wrote the following code in javascript.

```js
document.onkeypress = function() { myFunction() };
function myFunction() {
    let tags = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (tag of tags) {
        tag.value = tag.value.replace('TT', 'Talk To You later.');
    }
}
```

But when I installed this extension on chrome. I did work. But I have some problems. Such as it does not work in the Google Docs workplace. It only works where the input box is. But I want this extension to replace the text in any type of user inputs. Is there a way to access all the input tags (input box, text area) and their values? Is there a way to do this in a better way?

Thanks.

Comment: It's only going to work where your input is because you've selected the input element.
Can you use a JQuery selector to make life easier?

Comment: using JQuery how will Do it it ? access all user input values

Comment: Why would you expect this to effect Google Docs? The text in a Google Doc is a span element, not an input element

Comment: Yeah, I got that. Google Docs is not using the input element. It is a shortcut based app that replaces certain abbreviation to their full forms. So I want to access all user input text tags. Is there something we can do to solve this?

Comment: if you can use Jquery you can use a selector such as $("span")